# Selenium Python Twitter. Problem when HeadLess = True

Tags: python, selenium, class, web-scraping, twitter

I have done the next function to use twitter with Selenium.

If i put the HeadLess = False, it works perfect but when I put HeadLess = True, it doesnt find the elements by the class.

Some Help?

```
opciones=Options()

opciones.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
opciones.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

opciones.headless=False


def twittear():    
    
    url = 'https://twitter.com/login'
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=opciones)
    driver.get(url)
    
    try:
        # cookies
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-901oao css-16my406 css-bfa6kz r-poiln3 r-a023e6 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0'.replace(' ', '.')).click()
        time.sleep(1)

    except:
        
        None
    
    
    # Introduzco el mail
    
    time.sleep(10)
    
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu'.replace(' ', '.')).send_keys(user)
    time.sleep(2)                     
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu'.replace(' ', '.')).send_keys(u'\ue007')                    

    time.sleep(3)
    
    
    # Introduzco username
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu'.replace(' ', '.')).send_keys(user)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu'.replace(' ', '.')).send_keys(u'\ue007')   
    
    time.sleep(3)
    
    # Introduzco password
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu'.replace(' ', '.')).send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu'.replace(' ', '.')).send_keys(u'\ue007')   
    
    time.sleep(3)

    # Twitt
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr'.replace(' ', '.')).send_keys(gift_link)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-l5o3uw r-42olwf r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-19u6a5r r-2yi16 r-1qi8awa r-1ny4l3l r-ymttw5 r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr'.replace(' ', '.')).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm surprised it finds the elements at all, headless or not, as Selenium doesn't allow to locate elements by compound classes.

Try doing this, see if it makes a difference:

Change this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu'.replace(' ', '.')).send_keys(user)
```

to:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "r-30o5oe") and contains (@class, "r-1niwhzg")]').replace(' ', '.')).send_keys(user)
```

Comment: I have tried with that XPATH but it doesnt work. I have done with the Xpath and it works the same than with the previous. If I use HeadLedd = False, Works, If HeadLess = true. It doesnt find the elements: